# How manage missing value with SVM prediction

Tags: svm, prediction, missing-data

How can we manage missing value when we train a SVM Model ?

In particulary, if the SVM model is already train, how can we predict the class of a new observation if there is missing value ?

Thanks

Comment: Data cleansing, imputation, and the treatment of missing data is always an important part of the model building process... No matter what fancy algorithm you decide to use.

Answer (score 0):

If the SVM was trained on a dataset including a feature, and was not given any additional features to represent the "missingness" quality of a the given feature, then it simply cannot be used to make predictions on a new datapoint in which that feature is missing.

Some models would be able to handle this situation, because they are based on a full, probabilistic model of the data.  If this was the case you could marginalize on the missing predictor and get an "average" prediction over all possible values of the predictor.  SVM is not at all probabilistic, so in this case you have really no options.